# Converting a command line argument into char

Tags: c

I'm working with a command line arguments for the first time and I need to convert one of the string arguments to a character for testing. I tried testing it as a string and it wasn't working. In the program the user needs to enter an e or E or d or D (sample input at top of code). I haven't done much with conversions in C either so any help would be great. Thanks.

Input is: `./filename 4 1 7 e`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char letter = argv[4];
   if(argc != 5)
   {
      printf("Error - wrong number of inputs args\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')
   {
      printf("Error - E or D not entered\n");
      return -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: `char letter = argv[4][0];` This should go after the `argc` check.

Comment: Why are you not checking  `argc`? `argv [4]` might not exist

Comment: `char *argv[]` means, loosely speaking, "an array of _strings_, or, an array of chains of characters". How do you extract a single character from a chain of chars, then?

Comment: Reverse two lines and add a 2nd dimension to the index. `if(argc < 5) {/* horror */} char letter = argv[4][0];`

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line argument was actually entered by the user.

Comment: regarding: `if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')` this statement will ALWAYS evaluate to `true`  perhaps you meant: `if(letter != 'd' && letter != 'D' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'E')

Answer (score 5):

`argv` is of type `char **`, such that `char c = argv[4]` assigns a pointer to a character value; this should actually give a warning / error.

If you want to assign the first letter of the 4th argument, write `char c = *(argv[4])` or `char c = argv[4][0]`

And dont't forget to check if you have enough arguments provided *before* accessing `argv[4]`, i.e.

```
if (argc > 4) {
  char c = *(argv[4]);
  ...
```

Note  further that `if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')` rarely makes sense  since for any `letter` condition `letter != 'd' || letter != 'D'` is always true, because `letter` cannot be both `d` and `D` at the  same time. you probably meant `&&`...

Comment: `if (argc > 4)` does nto make sense when he has has `if (argc !=5)` clause.

Comment: @GRC The dereference happens before `if (argc != 5)`.

Comment: what I meant is that `if (argc > 4)` would accept any number of arguments larger than 4, which is bad idea. I upvoted your answer but this is simply bad idea and you should always limit number of arguments or if you are planning on having no arguments at all put `int main (void)`

Answer (score 5):

A string is simply an array of characters, terminated by a null.  So, access the first character in the array:

```
char letter = argv[4][0];
```

Also `if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')`  is always true, because `letter` cannot be both d and D at the same time.  You probably meant `if(letter != 'd' && letter != 'D' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'E')`

Answer (score 2):

To add to the current answers:

`if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')`

This expression will always evaluate to true. I think you mean to use `&&` here instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to 'C' and I can see you are struggling with pointers, I will try to explain what `argv` is. In reality `argv` is of type `char **argv` which is the same as `char *argv[]` which is the same as `char argv[][]`. Also all arguments are terminated with `\0` like any `C` string.

However even if you do understand pointers and fix those problems you have logical errors. Some are given by answers (@Josh pointed for this)

```
if(letter != 'd' || letter != 'D' || letter != 'e' || letter != 'E')
```

should be:

```
if(letter != 'd' && letter != 'D' && letter != 'e' && letter != 'E')
```

Another one is: 
You want to capture **ONE** letter of an argument and check if it is `d` or `e` as pointed by others

```
char letter = argv[4];
```

should be

```
char letter = argv[4][0];
```

but that would create another problem. What if you type `debug` as your  last argument first letter would still be 'd', but argument would not be 'd'. Which if you fix this line as suggested by Joshua from:

your code would fail if your `argv[4]` is `debug`. What you need to do is check if it is exactly one letter.

```
if (argv[4][1] != '\0') {
   printf ("5th argument is incomatible\n");
   return -1;
}
```

This checks if second character of argument is '\0', thus meaning that argv[4] contains only one letter and terminates with '\0'.

And another problem is referencing before checking if you have enough arguments.

```
char letter = argv[4];
if(argc != 5)
{
   printf("Error - wrong number of inputs args\n");
   return -1;
}

/* more code */
```

This would give you `segfautl` if you are lucky :). So to avoid segfautl it should be:

```
if(argc != 5)
{
   printf("Error - wrong number of inputs args\n");
   return -1;
}

char letter = argv[4][0];

/* more code */
```